# Bootstrap Modal + AJAX

Tags: ajax, bootstrap

Нужен пример реализации модального окна, с загрузкой содержимого по AJAX (модальные окна из Bootstrap).

Comment: Если нужен пример, значит какие-то знания уже есть. Может быть знаний даже достаточно на то, чтобы решить задачу самому, но вот только что-то и где-то не получается.

Может быть стоит вместо примера попытаться разобраться что и почему работает не правильно?

К тому же - получите пример, воспользуетесь им, а затем чуть какая проблема - опять бежать за советом?

Че-то мне кажется, что надо разобраться самому. Не просить "примеров", а просить объяснений - почему что-то работает не так как того хочется.

Потом пригодится.

Comment: пачиму ви тгавите новичков?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

это верстка:

```
<div class="modal">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3>ЗАголовок</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="my-content"></div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn">OK</button>
</div>
</div>
```

это код, который будет подгружать что-то в тело окна:

```
$.ajax({type: "POST", url: "script.php", data:somedata, 
    dataType:"text", timeout:30000, async:false,
    error: function(xhr) {
        console.log('Ошибка!'+xhr.status+' '+xhr.statusText); 
    },
    success: function(a) {
        document.getElementById("my-content").innerHTML=a;
    }  
});
```

конечно же, должен быть какой-то скрипт script.php которому будет передаваться запрос, описанный в somedata, и ответ его желателен в текстовом виде, можно с тэгами хтмл.
Пример обобщенный, на понимание.

Answer (score 1):

Недавно решал подобную задачу, дабы не придумывать велосипед, погуглил...
Вот отличный вариант диалогов, в связке с бутстрапом - jquery.dialog2.js 
https://github.com/Nikku/jquery-bootstrap-scripting/

Comment: что-то не увидел там возможности подгрузки чего-либо по аякс...

Comment: Внизу страницы по линку выше, документация с примерами. А вообще вот основные фишки этого диалогового окна.

Features:
Ajax content
Ajax links and form submission in the dialog
Loading indicator
Localization
No dependencies to jQuery.UI
Control via html markup possible
.
Реализовал с помощью этого плагина диалоги регистрации, восстановления аккаунта, и разные вспомогательные.